# Error 1140 using the query builder of Laravel and count aggregate

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to do the following SQL query using the Laravel query builder:

```
select `source`, `customer_id`, COUNT(id) from `requests` where `source` = "ATC" and `customer_id` = 1234567
```

I tried with the following code but it doesn't work correctly:

```
DB::table('requests')->select('source', 'customer_id', DB::raw('COUNT(id)'))->where('source', '=', 'ATC')->where('customer_id', '=', '1234567')->get();
```

I reiceived the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'opadidb.requests.source'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `source`, `customer_id`, COUNT(id) from `requests` where `source` = ATC and `customer_id` = 1234567)
```

Can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate functions like `sum`,`count`,`min`,`max`,`avg` when selected with other columns it must have a `groupBy` clause for one of these column.

your query have two columns `'source'` & `'customer_id'`  you must add a group by to both of them:

```
DB::table('requests')->select('source', 'customer_id', DB::raw('COUNT(id)'))
->where('source', '=', 'ATC')->where('customer_id', '=', '1234567')
->groupBy('source','customer_id')->get();
```

Comment: Uhm in my case your queries don't work... I continue receiving that error.

Comment: try grouping both columns like this `groupBy('customer_id','source')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't also run the first query as it is stated in the message without making changes on your query or your mysql settings;

> In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains non-aggregated column 'opadidb.requests.source'.

- You change your mysql settings to enable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, more info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)
- You change the query to something like this by adding `group by` clause at the end depending on what results you want to achieve.
- If it is enabled, then as a third option you can change your `database.php` file to make change `strict` key of your database from `true` to `false`